# Slow File Transfer with IPSecSlow File Transfer with IPSec Site to Site VPN to Azure VM

Tags: vpn, azure, virtual-machines, ipsec

I have managed to successfully establish an IPSEC tunnel (Site to Site VPN) between my Azure environment and my on-prem RRAS server using IKEV2.

My Azure setup is as follows:

192.168.0.0/16 Address space with 2 subnets: default subnet 192.168.0.0/24 and 192.168.1.0/24 as my gateway subnet.

My on-prem is as follows:

10.0.32.0/24

I have a server on Azure that is 192.168.0.4 and server on my on-prem side that is 10.0.32.46. I can Ping both ways and I even managed to join my Azure server to the AD domain that is on my on-prem side.

However, when I do file transfer from On-prem server to Azure server it seem to hang. But from Azure to On-prem I can transfer files just fine at high speed.

NOTE: both on-prem and azure have high bandwidth and Im sure the issue is nothing to do with bandwidth.

From on prem to Azure file transfer works but Extremely slow. I am only seem to be able to copy files less than 10KB. anything larger than that seem to make it hang. Therefore, the issue is not firewalls or ports since the copy works.

I used Iperf.exe to check the connection and when I have my Azure server as a listening server I can see that I am not receiving anything (0 data ) from on prem side but can send to it. But when my on prem side is listening using Iperf I can see that I can send and receive data from azure end.

I tried changing the MTU on both ends lowering it down to 1400 and it didnt seem to fix the issue.

I used Wireshark to investigate the issue further, and I can see lots of re-transmission,duplicate TCP from my Azure end.

I do not know what else I can do, I know that the issue resides on the azure networking side, and im sure its not the Azure server (windows 2019) since I span up another server (2012 R2) on Azure and it ended up having the same behavior.

NOTE: I had to enable SMB1 to join my Azure server to my domain on the on-prem side, however file transfer uses SMB2. I thought there might be a protocol mixup but wireshark shows that file transfer uses SMB2 and SMB2 is enabled on both ends. Ive also tested this with FTP (filezilla) as well and experiencing the same issue. Therefore I dont think its a protocol issue such as SMB1 or SMB2.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you let me know the connection speed for the on prem and the router you're using?

Comment: 100Mb up and down.